# Autolayout contraint error

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout

So this autolayout error. Which I know why it is there but I am not sure how can I fix it. As with error its clear that its not able to resolve the constraints.
In portrait mode all 47 episode are listed and can be scrolled to. But in landscape mode it cant, which is clear as height of table is not changing thats way its is still down there but can't scroll to it.

[image: Screen 1]

[image: screen 2]

So this is how I have setup.

[image: View hierarchy]

Where as view controller has two view which works as placeholder upper is of for iAds and lower is holding table view. Idea was behind this. if ad is not loaded I will set height of View to zero which holds iADBanner. So that Table view takes up all space. (Got this idea from Ray Wenderlich's app level me up.) I was struggling with auto layout initially but I made it right so that view are taking up all width when sim goes to portrait mode. but somehow I am not able to fix the height of view which holds tableView.
Below are the screenshot of constraints.

[image: constraint 1 of 2]
[image: Constraint 2 of 2]

I tried to be as descriptive as I can. but I am looking for more than just answer. I want to get to know this completely so that I will most likely won't have problem in future. I have finished raywenderlich tutorial already. So Any other pointer would be very much appreciate along with the answer.

```
2014-07-30 21:40:37.326 Test[85608:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)  (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa5afbc0 UIView:0xa69b7d0.width == 0.682303*UIView:0xa69b830.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa5afc80 V:|-(50)-[UIView:0xa69b830]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xa69b7d0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa5afdc0 V:[UIView:0xa69b830]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0xa5a8410]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xa5a7d20 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0xa5a8410(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0xa5af490 _UILayoutGuide:0xa5a8410.bottom == UIView:0xa69b7d0.bottom>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xa792d10 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0xa69b7d0(480)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0xa792dd0 h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0xa69b7d0(271)]>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xa5afdc0 V:[UIView:0xa69b830]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0xa5a8410]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger. The
methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView
listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it looks like you're adding some views/constraints programmatically? I say that because you have a couple `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint`s. These are disabled by default when you add constraints in Interface Builder. If this is true, you might try setting the `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to `NO` on the view you added.

Comment: No, @daltonclaybrook I am not doing that programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of constraints in the error log is the key to understanding this type of problem.  What you want to do is look at it carefully to correlate which lines refer to which constraints in your code/ui builder, and which hexadecimal address refers to which view.

1. `V:[UIView:0xa69b830]-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0xa5a8410]` is a constraint setting the bottom of a UIView to a layout guide, so most likely that's the last constraint in your screenshot "Vertical Space - Bottom layout guide - TableVi..." (presumably that's TableViewHolder truncated). That means `UIView:0xa69b830` is your `TableViewHolder`.
2. `V:|-(50)-[UIView:0xa69b830]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xa69b7d0 )` is the constraint tying the *top* of TableViewHolder 50px from its superview, which must be `UIView:0xa69b7d0`.
3. `UIView:0xa69b7d0.width == 0.682303*UIView:0xa69b830.height` looks like an aspect ratio constraint between the superview width and the TableViewHolder height.
4. `h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0xa69b7d0(480)]` and `h=--& v=--& V:[UIView:0xa69b7d0(271)]` are constraints on the superview that's derived from its *autoresizingMask*, where the width=480px, height=271px, and their top/left/width/height are fixed (based on `h=--& v=--&`). This is sort of the standard setup for the root view of a view controller — it's dimensions are managed manually by the view controller to fill the screen.

So once you have all that, you can see what the problem is: the superview has fixed dimensions 480x271.  Meanwhile, TableViewHolder's height is being dictated by multiple conflicting constraints:

- #1 and #2 are trying to stretch it vertically to fill its superview with a 50px margin at the top, so height = 271-50 = 221px.
- #3 is trying to set the height as a ratio of the superview's width: height = 480/0.6823 = 703.5px
- 221 != 730.5!

Something's gotta give, and the OS just happened to pick #1, so the bottom of TableViewHolder extends past the bottom of the layout guide, making it stick out past the edge of the screen and inaccessible.

Your fix will likely involve getting rid of that aspect ratio constraint, but there might be other issues that appear once you fix that.  Good luck!

Comment: @Danial : Thanks a lot. I learned couple of things. here first never read error in that small box pf debugger. You will never never know what problem it is. Second of course how you explained about the constraints. I wish in tutorials/books they were explaining this clearly. Do you recommend any book or link to make my understanding better on Autolayout. Yes for sure as soon as I removed that ratio constraint. It worked. :) thanks for pin pointing my problem.

Comment: @Alix, I don't have any books to recommend, but I highly recommend watching Apple's [WWDC videos](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) — just search for "auto layout".  There are many techniques they haven't documented elsewhere.

Comment: Watching those videos. Thanks for the recommendation.